# Python : Calling Parent Function in child Class

Tags: python

In Python I try to call a method from a Parent Class in a Child class but I get error.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.value = 0
        
    def __updateValue(self):
        self.value +=1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        
    def stuff(self):
        self.value = 6
        self.__updateValue()
    

childObject = Child()
childObject.stuff()

print(childObject.atr)
```

The error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\test2.py", line 18, in <module>
    childObject.stuff()
  File "...\test2.py", line 14, in stuff
    self.__updateValue()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute '_Child__updateValue'. Did you mean: '_Parent__updateValue'?
```

I try replacing `self.__updateValue()` with `super().__updateValue()` but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to call a Parent method within a Child method ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Why make it private when you want to call it in other classes? (That's what `__` at the beggining of method name signifies)

Comment: Normally a child class *can* call parent class methods, in exactly the way you've tried to do here - but by naming the method with two leading underscores, you've made it private to the parent class.

Comment: You have used `__` that created name mangling so you have to use appropriate name to call that function.

Comment: Thank you all ! It was the problem. I use ```__``` to identify "private" method, I didn't know it was an issue

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help.

Using `__` at the begining of the function name was the issue.